Apache Spark Operator Metrics
I have sucessfully rolled out Apache Spark via the Operator version to Kubernetes on GKE. This works fine and functionally its fine. I recently started to explore what Spark Metrics could be gathered and had the following setup in my helm for metrics
    helm:
      values: |
        metrics:
          enable: true
          port: 10254
          portName: metrics
          endpoint: /metrics
          prefix: ""
          spark.metrics:
            spark.ui.prometheus.enabled: true
        podMonitor:
          enable: true
          labels: {}
          jobLabel: spark-operator-podmonitor
          podMetricsEndpoint:
            scheme: http
            interval: 5s
        webhook:
          enable: true
          port: 443
          namespaceSelector: spark-webhook-enabled=true

This works fine and I see the basic metrics in prometheus. I have a need to go further a look at driver and executor metrics and expected the setup below to cover that but when port-forwarding i notice its just basic stats . I've had a look around and can't find. how to expose these specific metrics. Any help much appreciated
